# Border clipped off in Chrome but not IE or Edge

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

This CSS & HTML shows three text boxes that are completely wrapped in their borders when viewed in IE and Edge.  When viewed in Chrome (or on my Android's browser) the right side of the border is clipped off.

I can make it work by adding a trailing " " to each span, but I'd rather learn whether I'm doing something wrong...

```html
<html>
<body>
<style>
.link-bubble {
    float:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border: thin solid blue;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:antiquewhite;
    padding:4px 6px 6px 6px;
    margin:2px;
}
</style>
<div style="float:right; width:30%; text-align:center; line-height:40px;">
    <span class="link-bubble">
        <a href="/Services/target1">First service offered</a>
    </span>
    <span class="link-bubble">
        <a href="/Services/target2">Second service offered</a>
    </span>
    <span class="link-bubble">
        <a href="/Services/target3">Third service offered</a>
    </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems something to do with the `width:30%;` on the `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why that specific behavior is happening and the discrepancies between browsers, but I would bet it has to do with `white-space:nowrap` and the parent elements `width: 30%` and some quirkyness with that.

Instead of trying to work around that quirk, a much easier way to do this is change the `display` of the `.link-bubble`'s from `inline` to `block`.  You can do this with the `display: block` on the class, or just change the elements from `span` to `div` or other block elements.  [Here's some good reading on the box model](https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/css-box-model/) - I'd also recommend reading up on css flexbox and grid, much easier and more modern way of handling positioning of elements vs divs and floats.

Also, If you really need the `white-space: nowrap`, add that style to the inner element.  See my example below.

```html
<html>
<body>
<style>
.link-bubble {
overflow: hidden;
border: thin solid blue;
border-radius:10px;
background-color:antiquewhite;
padding:4px 6px 6px 6px;
display: block;
margin: 2px;
}

.link-bubble a { white-space: nowrap; }
</style>
<div style="float:right; text-align:center; width: 30%; line-height: 40px;">
    <span class="link-bubble">
        <a href="/Services/target1">First service offered</a>
    </span>
    <span class="link-bubble">
        <a href="/Services/target2">Second service offered</a>
    </span>
    <span class="link-bubble">
        <a href="/Services/target3">Third service offered</a>
    </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Client wants a collection of links on the right side of the page that are are basically "corralled".  Each link can be a different size, can't  be split in half (hence white-space:nowrap;) so the first line may hold 5 links, the second line 2, the third line 4, and all that would change as the client re-sizes the window.
display:block; forces a fixed width column as wide as the widest text - so that's out.
I had never used flexbox before - thanks for the tip - I definitely will be using it in the future but in this case it also would force fixed-width columns.

Comment: No problem - if you found the answer useful, could you mark it as accepted to close this out?

Comment: For now I'd like to see if anyone else can explain why that is happening and what I can do to make it work as (apparently) designed - without forcing block layout.  I don't think I'm ready to close it out yet, but thank you again for your guidance.